# VB.Net Query CSV File

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable

I have a a csv file I need to process to find just a few line items.  I followed the tutorial [here](http://burnignorance.com/vb-net-tricks/reading-csv-file-and-extracting-records-to-datatable-in-vb-net/) for reading in a CSV file into a DataTable.  It worked very well when my query was:

```
SELECT * FROM <NameOfCsvFile>
```

This is great but it returns the whole CSV file as a DataTable.  I only want a portion of the file to check for known errors.  So I modified my query to be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <NameOfCsvFile> WHERE Column1 IN (Int1,Int2,Int3,Int4,Int5)
```

When I checked the DataTables output in the debugger it had the right row count (being 5) but the list of rows was equal to NOTHING.

How can I get this to work MS's query interface instead of manually looping through the whole CSV file to return the 5 records I seek out of hundreds?

Comment: The import might have converted your integer values to string, try ```Column1 IN ('Int1', 'Int2'...```

Comment: There is no reason what you have wont work.  Of course you could load all the rows and apply that WHERE as a filter.  Depending on the data, it is possible that OleDB is converting to text on some or all columns. That assumes that `Column1` represents a column name and not some attempt to just load certain columns in that list

Comment: @Anand I've tried to convert them to strings and I get nothing back for a datatable so I don't think they're being convert to strings.

Comment: @Plutonix exactly.  It looks sound to me especially since my row count is coming back correct but now rows are actually being returned.

Comment: You can use the visualizer or debug window to "look into" the datatable.  I doubt that the DataTable is broken (reporting rows when there are none).  More likely how you are displaying of using them

Comment: Ok I figured it out.  The query was always working.  What I forgot to do was call the Select() method to get rows in a readable format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The query worked perfectly but the debugger doesn't allow you to see what rows are returned as they haven't been decoded yet.  Calling `Dim rows() as DataRows = dt.Select("")` allowed me to see the actual results of the CSV file query.

All is good in the world now